# one stdout to one stdin from java to python

Tags: java, python, stdout, stdin

I am having this java code

```
public static main void (String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("this is iteration 1");
    System.out.println("this is iteration 2");
    System.out.println("this is iteration 3");
    System.out.println("this is iteration 4");
}
```

Python

```
import sys 

try:
    while True:
        data = raw_input()
        print "in python " + data
except:
    print error
```

Desired output

```
In python : this is iteration 1
In python : this is iteration 2
In python : this is iteration 3
In python : this is iteration 4
```

Current output

```
In python : this is iteration 1
In python : this is iteration 2
In python : this is iteration 3
In python : this is iteration 4
Error
```

Basically what it does is that it was able to print out the four lines from stdout to stdin from java to python. However, when stdout has finished, i would like it to be blocking instead of running again.

My second question would be that, are the system.out.println all piped to the stdout buffer and the stdin reads them or they are read line by line?

My command to run the code is this

```
java -jar stdOut.jar | python testStdin.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost everything is like you intended it to be. Have a look at [`EOFError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.EOFError) to see why this happens.

```
import sys 

try:
    while True:
        data = raw_input()
        print "in python " + data
except EOFError:
    pass
```

So basically you're reading, until the end of the stream is reached. If you want the input to block, the output should stay open as well.

For your second question, just delay the output for a short while somewhere in the middle. You'll already see the first lines, while waiting for the rest of them.